# CFL Fixtures: one lamp stays constant, the other cycles on an off

Tags: light-fixture

My daughter just had extensive remodeling in her house. Both children's bedrooms now have cfl two bulb ceiling fixtures.  Both fixtures, when switched on, start out with one bulb lit.  After a few seconds the second bulb comes one for a few seconds and then goes off.  This pattern continues while the fixture is on - one bulb constant, the other rhythmically cycling on.  What might be causing this?

Comment: How hot are the lamp bases getting? What style of fixture are we talking about here?

Comment: Are these new fixtures or old?

Answer (score 2):

Continual cycling of fluorescent lamps on and off was once a symptom of a [bad thermal starter switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Starterp.jpg) or a dying fluorescent tube, but if your daughter's house was recently remodeled, it's *very* unlikely an ethical contractor would have installed such a lamp.

If this is *truly* a [CFL (compact fluorescent lamp)](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Shapes-of-compact-fluorescent-lamps-CFL_fig1_221736226), designed to fit an incandescent lamp socket (Edison base, e.g. [E26 in USA](https://support.lifx.com/hc/en-us/articles/201622624-E26-vs-E27-What-s-the-difference)), just replace *both* lamps with modern LED lamps, which are more efficient, longer lasting and less expensive, and come in a variety of colors such as [this "warm white" (2700 K) model](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Cree-60W-Equivalent-Soft-White-2700K-A19-Dimmable-Exceptional-Light-Quality-LED-Light-Bulb-2-Pack-TA19-08027MDFH25-12DE26-1-12/303880968).